# run commands per boot via cloud config

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I am passing cloud config via --user-data-file argument when starting ec2 instance from canonic ubuntu images.

It works well but the problem is that some of its commands need to run every boot (i.e. when we stop/start or reboot the instance). Is there a way (or section in cloud config) that allows to describe commands that should run on every boot, not only upon instance creation?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need cloud-init to do boot time command execution. Things you want to look at is crontab, upstart scripts, /etc/rc.local and /etc/init.d. There are a lot of options. It depends on the distribution as well.